# Can Dirac semimetal have no surface states?

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, topological-insulators, weyl-semimetal

There are models of the 3D Dirac semimetal. For example, proposed [in this paper](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevB.85.195320), when $k_\pm=k_x\pm ik_y$ and $M=m-|\vec{k}|^2$,
$$H=\begin{bmatrix}
M & k_+ & 0 & 0 \\
k_- & -M & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & M & -k_- \\
0 & 0 & -k_+ & -M
\end{bmatrix}$$ describes two Dirac points at $(0,0,\pm\sqrt{m})$. It is actually 2D BHZ model of topological insulator stacked along $k_z$ in between the two Dirac points. Hence we will have surface states.

However, is ther any model of Dirac semimetal **without** surface states? In my understanding, this is just a possible case for Dirac semimetal as long as it bears Dirac points. But I hope to know if any concrete model or case with at least two Dirac points.

Comment: https://arxiv.org/abs/1510.07698 at page 24 of this I suppose Witten generalizes the boundary properties of Dirac semi-metals. You may have your answer there.